# Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery] error display when running Get-AzTableRow command on VSTS azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I am trying to run azure powershell on VSTS with Get-AzTableRow command.

**Powershell :**

```
$ConfigurationPortalName = "xxxx"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxx"
$Location = "West Europe"
$SubscriptionName = "xxxx"
$SubscriptionId = "xxxx"
$AdHocReleaseDefinitionId = "xxxx"
$MultipleEnvReleaseDefId = "xxxx"
$StorageConnectionString = "xxxx"
$StorageContainerName = "xxxx"
$PortalStorageAccountName = "xxxx"
$SkuName = "Standard_LRS"
$tableName = "Subscription"
$partitionKey = "Subscription"
$storageAccountName = $PortalStorageAccountName.ToLower()

write-host "*Install modules*"
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.5.2 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -RequiredVersion 1.3.1 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -RequiredVersion 1.3.0 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
Install-Module -Name AzTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.2 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force 

write-host "*Current version*"
Get-Module Az.Storage
Get-Module Az.Accounts
Get-Module AzTable
Get-Module Az.Resources

write-host "*remove module*"
try
{
    Remove-Module -Name AzureRM.Profile -Force
    Remove-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
    Remove-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force
    Remove-Module -Name AzTable -Force
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}

write-host "*Import module version*"
Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.5.2 -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Resources -RequiredVersion 1.3.1 -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Storage -RequiredVersion 1.3.0 -Force
Import-Module -Name AzTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.2 -Force

write-host "*Final version*"
Get-Module Az.Accounts
Get-Module Az.Storage
Get-Module AzTable
Get-Module Az.Resources

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
Write-host "strgacc : " $storageAccount

if (!$storageAccount) 
{
    $storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -Name $storageAccountName `
        -Location $Location `
        -SkuName $SkuName `
        -Kind Storage

    Write-host 'Storage Account Created !!!'
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'Storage Account Already Exist !!!'
}

$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName
$newStorageConnectionString = [string]::Format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net', $storageAccountName, $storageAccountKeys[0].Value);

$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ConfigurationPortalName;
$appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings;

$hash = @{};
ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) 
{
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value;
}

if ($hash['Config:Storage:ConnectionString'] -ne $newStorageConnectionString) 
{
    $hash['Config:Storage:ConnectionString'] = $newStorageConnectionString;

    Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ConfigurationPortalName -AppSettings $hash;

    Write-host 'WebApp Configured With New Storage Account Key successfully !!!'
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'WebApp Already Configured With Storage Account Key !!!' 
}

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

#Get Storage Tabel Reference
$cloudTable  = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorVariable ev -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CloudTable

#If no reference then create new table else check for default entry
if ($ev) 
{
    New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName –Context $ctx;
    $cloudTable  = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorVariable ev -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CloudTable
    Write-host 'Table Created :' $cloudTable
}

Write-Host "Table :" $cloudTable

if ($cloudTable) 
{
    #$rows = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -partitionKey $partitionKey | ft
    $rows = "aaa"
    write-host "Rows :" $rows
    #if (!$rows)
    if ($rows) 
    {
        Add-AzTableRow `
            -table $cloudTable `
            -partitionKey $partitionKey `
            -rowKey $SubscriptionName `
            -property @{`
                            "SubscriptionId"          = $SubscriptionId; `
                            "AdHocReleaseDefinitionId" = $AdHocReleaseDefinitionId; `
                            "MultipleEnvReleaseDefId"  = $MultipleEnvReleaseDefId; `
                            "StorageConnectionString" = $StorageConnectionString; `
                            "StorageContainerName"    = $StorageContainerName
                        }

        Write-host 'Row successfully inserted !!!'
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-host 'Default rows already configured !!!'
    }
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'Table Storage Reference Not Found !!!'
}
Write-Host 'done'
```

**Error :**

```
2019-05-17T08:13:38.6380364Z ##[error]Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

**Note :** Running fine in local powershell ISE. Using agent 'Hosted VS2017'in VSTS

**Version of installed modules in local and VSTS are same when i run the below commands to check:**

```
Get-Module Az.Storage
Get-Module Az.Accounts
Get-Module AzTable
Get-Module Az.Resources
```

then version i am getting :

```
Az.Accounts 1.5.2
Az.Storage 1.3.0
AzTable 2.0.2
Az.Resources 1.3.1
```

Now the new error displayed on line :

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
```

**Error :**

```
2019-05-22T10:38:30.2164835Z ##[error]Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
```

Comment: Do you need import module to run?

Comment: already imported the module using commands : 

Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force

Install-Module -Name AzTable -AllowClobber -Force -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: Run "Get-module" after the issue repro, What's the output？ Will the "Az.Storage 1.3.0" be show in the output? Will other version of "*.Storage" module be show?

Comment: @WeiWei-Microsoft When i run the command 'Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Storage' then version i get is '1.3.0' but when i run 'Get-module' then version of 'Az.Storage' i am getting is '1.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to run the script on VSTS :

**Note : Azure Powershell version must be 4.* (preview)**

```
$ConfigurationPortalName = "xxxx"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxx"
$Location = "West Europe"
$SubscriptionName = "xxxx"
$SubscriptionId = "xxxx"
$AdHocReleaseDefinitionId = "xxxx"
$MultipleEnvReleaseDefId = "xxxx"
$StorageConnectionString = "xxxx"
$StorageContainerName = "xxxx"
$SkuName = "Standard_LRS"
$tableName = "Subscription"
$partitionKey = "Subscription"
$storageAccountName = "xxxx"

write-host "*Install Modules*"
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.5.2 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -RequiredVersion 1.3.0 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
Install-Module -Name AzTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.2 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force 

write-host "*remove module*"
Remove-Module -Name Az.Accounts -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Remove-Module -Name Az.Storage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Remove-Module -Name AzTable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

write-host "*Import Module version*"
Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.5.2 -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Storage -RequiredVersion 1.3.0 -Force
Import-Module -Name AzTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.2 -Force

write-host "*Get Module version currently in use*"
Get-Module Az.Accounts
Get-Module Az.Storage
Get-Module AzTable

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName

if (!$storageAccount) 
{
    $storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -Name $storageAccountName `
        -Location $Location `
        -SkuName $SkuName `
        -Kind Storage

    Write-host 'Storage Account Created !!!'
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'Storage Account Already Exist !!!'
}

$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName
$newStorageConnectionString = [string]::Format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net', $storageAccountName, $storageAccountKeys[0].Value);
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ConfigurationPortalName;
$appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings;
$hash = @{};

ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) 
{
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value;
}

if ($hash['Config:Storage:ConnectionString'] -ne $newStorageConnectionString) 
{
    $hash['Config:Storage:ConnectionString'] = $newStorageConnectionString;
    Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ConfigurationPortalName -AppSettings $hash;
    Write-host 'WebApp Configured With New Storage Account Key successfully !!!'
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'WebApp Already Configured With Storage Account Key !!!' 
}

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

#Get Storage Tabel Reference
$cloudTable  = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx -ErrorVariable ev -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CloudTable

#If no reference then create new table else check for default entry
if($ev)
{
    New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName –Context $ctx;
    $cloudTable  = (Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx).CloudTable
    Write-host 'Table created successfully !!!'
}

Write-Host "Table name :" $cloudTable

if ($cloudTable) 
{
    $rows = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -partitionKey $partitionKey | ft
    if (!$rows)
    {
        Add-AzTableRow `
            -table $cloudTable `
            -partitionKey $partitionKey `
            -rowKey $SubscriptionName `
            -property @{`
                            "SubscriptionId"          = $SubscriptionId; `
                            "AdHocReleaseDefinitionId" = $AdHocReleaseDefinitionId; `
                            "MultipleEnvReleaseDefId"  = $MultipleEnvReleaseDefId; `
                            "StorageConnectionString" = $StorageConnectionString; `
                            "StorageContainerName"    = $StorageContainerName
                        }

        Write-host 'Row successfully inserted !!!'
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-host 'Default Row already configured !!!'
    }
}
else 
{
    Write-host 'Table Storage Reference Not Found !!!'
}

Write-Host 'Completed !!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the issue that you provide:

> 2019-05-17T08:13:38.6380364Z ##[error]Cannot find type
>   [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]: verify that the assembly
>   containing this type is loaded

The reason is that you need to use the module `Az.Storage` version 1.1.0 or greater than. Take a look at the [troubling](https://paulomarquesc.github.io/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/) in this document. And you can use the PowerShell command:

```
Update-Module -Name Az
```

Then open a new PowerShell session and it will work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193739/discussion-on-answer-by-charles-xu-cannot-find-type-microsoft-azure-cosmos-tabl).

Answer (score 0):

based on [Manage organization billing in Azure DevOps - Sprint 150 Update #Support for Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-150-update#support-for-azure-powershell-az-module)

`You need to install the Az module on your agent machine if you are using private agents.`

you should use private agent as you can't update the version of powershell module on hosed agent(eg: Hosted VS2017).